# Set and invalid field to None in django rest

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):

    field_1 = models.Integerfield(blank=True, null=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    field_2 = models.Integerfield(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       fields = (field_1, field_2)
```

When I try

```
r = ReportSerializer(data={'field_1':0, 'field_2': 50}
r.is_valid(True)
```

It raises:

```
{'field_1': ['Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 10.']}
```

Even if field_1 is not required (required=False)

I would like my report to be created with field_2 set and field_1 at None but cannot find a way to achieve this properly.

What would be a good way to achieve this, ie not raising ValidationError on optionnal fields.

Comment: what happens with data={'field_2': 50}, i assume the behaviour you are getting is because if you are providing a value for field_1, even if 0, should be valid. 0 =/= null or None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best shot would be to modify `field_1`'s value inside your serializer's `validate` method. You'd have to explicitly check if it's equal to 0 and, in case it is, change it to `None`.

```
def validate(self, data):
    if data['field_1'] == 0:
        data['field_1'] = None
    return super().validate(data)
```

Note, however, that changing a value inside `validate` is not a good practice.

Another option would be to remove your `MaxValueValidator` from your model field and change the value inside the serializer's `create` method. This would require that you validated if the value is lower than 10 and different from 0 inside `validate`. In other words, more code.

Last but not least, you can also make this change inside the view's `post` method, which is obviously called before the serializer's validation. Not the best practice either since it's ideal that all your input data is manipulated inside the serializer, but it's less code.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.data['field_1'] == 0:
        request.data['field_1'] = None
    super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I implemented the third solution ;)